# string to int ValueError Python

Tags: python, types, valueerror

if the string is '007w', then when it tries to return '007w' as integer, i want it to `return None` and `print('Cannot be converted)`. But without using the Try Except ValueError:

```
import random

def random_converter(x):
    selection = random.randint(1,5)
    if selection == 1:
        return int(x)
    elif selection == 2:
        return float(x)
    elif selection == 3:
        return bool(x)
    elif selection == 4:
        return str(x)
    else:
        return complex(x)


for _ in range(50):
    output = random_converter('007w')
    print(output, type(output))
```

Comment: why don't you want to use try except?

Comment: i would use try-expect but with `random.choice([int, float, bool, str, complex])(x)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Comment: See above comment, specially answer with isdigit()

Comment: @user1558604 challenging to find different ways to solve things and get around things the hard way, so in future problems I'll have a more analytical approach

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check whether a string in python can be parsed into a number or not. It will return true if all values are digits, and false otherwise.

Note that `isdigit()` is fairly limited in its ability - it [can't handle decimal points or negative numbers.](https://tdhopper.com/blog/testing-whether-a-python-string-contains-an-integer/) If you're expecting to parse anything more complicated than a positive integer, you may want to consider `try/except` instead.

---

```py
def parse(in_str):
  if(in_str.isdigit()):
    return int(in_str)
  else:
    print('Cannot be converted')
    return(None)

print(parse("1234"))
print(parse("007w"))
```

> 1234
>   Cannot be converted
>   None

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/StupidBriskScript)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `random.choice` for your decider and `str.isdigit` for checking if `x` can be converted:

```
def random_converter(x):
    selection = random.choice([int, float, bool, str, complex])
    if x.isdigit() or selection == bool:
        return selection(x)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: The same still applies for `str` and `float` for example

Comment: Now *that's* a pythonic answer. Almost feels taboo to think you can cast to any value in a string, +1